# How to change the value of a python list object one object at a time?

Tags: python

I'm working on a small program for booking payments using openpyxl and I have a problem. The code I'm using is a bit more complicated, but basically it comes down to this:

```
a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
e=0
mylist = [a,b,c,d,e]
```

Now I would like to take the first value that is equal to 0 and change it to 1. The other items should remain 0. So the values of list items would look like this:

```
mylist = [1,0,0,0,0]
```

So, the next time I run the program and call the function it would search for the next value that is equal to 0 and change it to 1. It would therefore change the list to look like this:

```
mylist = [1,1,0,0,0]
```

And so forth...

The problem is that a for loop changes all the values because every item meets the criteria of being a 0. So, my first idea is to use some sort of iterator, but I'm not sure about that. Is there some other way?

Comment: `for i, v in enumerate(mylist): if v == 0: mylist[i] = 1; break`…?

Comment: ``mylist[mylist.index(0)] += 1``?

Comment: I think that this is it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist[mylist.index(0)] = 1
```

This should be enough.